# How to verify volume successfully created/attached in boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm using boto3 `client.create_volume` and `client.attach_volume` APIs, but the return values are dictionaries, and the key `State` within the dictionary is `creating` for create_volume, and `attaching` for attach_volume. Is there any way to check if the volume is successfully created/attached within boto3?

Answer (score 10):

Fortunately, boto3 has a concept called **Waiters** that can do the waiting for you!

See: [EC2.Waiter.VolumeInUse](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.VolumeInUse)

> Polls `EC2.Client.describe_volumes()` every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

For those using ec2 client (`ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')`), you can do

> `ec2.get_waiter('volume_available').wait(VolumeIds=[new_volume['VolumeId']])`

Comment: For those using ec2 client (`ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')`), you can do `ec2.get_waiter('volume_available').wait(VolumeIds=[new_volume['VolumeId']])`

Answer (score 2):

See [describe_volumes](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_volumes)

Pass your `volume_id` and `describe_volumes` returns the information about:

**Creation State:**

```
'State': 'creating'|'available'|'in-use'|'deleting'|'deleted'|'error'
```

**Attachment State:**

```
'State': 'attaching'|'attached'|'detaching'|'detached'
```

and lot more information about your volume.

Comment: Do I need to sleep for sometime before calling describe volumes? if I immediately call describe volumes after create/attach volumes, the state may be still "creating"/"attaching"

Comment: Yes. Wait for the state to become `available` after create_volume. Else wait for few seconds. Waiting time may depend on size, type, availability zone of the volume. If it is not `available`, wait and try again. Once it becomes `available`, call `attach_volume`. Then wait for its state becomes `attached`.

Comment: Thanks. i don't understand why boto3 uses dictionary as returned value. boto2 is much easier to use. but boto2 doesn't have modify_volume API so I have to use boto3

Comment: @user284602 boto3 is behaving more correctly.  See the EC2 API Reference for what the EC2 Query API actually returns on the wire: [`AttachVolume`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AttachVolume.html), [`CreateVolume`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateVolume.html).  It's generally not optimal design to discard or hide part or all of the response.